# How to delete structure entries and use realloc to free memory

Tags: c, structure, realloc

I am trying to delete structure entries and then use `realloc` to free the memory. My structure is

```
typedef struct person {
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int number[10];
}person;
```

Im using a function to delete inputted entries

```
void delInfo(int*,person*);
```

The way the delete function is supposed to work is by locating said entry, shift back all records after that, then freeing last record with `realloc`. 
The code for it so far looks like this

```
void delInfo(int *num_entries,person*contacts){
    char delfirst[20];
    char dellast[20];

    printf("\n First Name: ");
    scanf("%s",delfirst);
    printf(" Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s",dellast);
    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<*num_entries;i++){
        if (delfirst==contacts[i].fname && dellast==contacts[i].lname){

        }
    }
}
```

So far I can search for a match with the first and last name, but dont know what happens if I move every entry "down one." If matching entry is contacts[i] something like

```
int c;
for (c=i+1;c<*num_entries;c++){
    contacts[i].fname=contacts[c].fname;
    contacts[i].lname=contacts[c].lname;
    contacts[i].number=contacts[c].number;
}
contacts=(person*)realloc(contacts,sizeof(contacts)*(num_entries-1));
```

If I do that to all entries AFTER the one I plan on deleting, do they just "overwrite" the entry I want to delete, then I can `realloc` to shorten the structure array and essentially free the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `i` is the index of the entry that you want to delete, all you really need to do is:

```
for (c = i; c < *num_entries - 1; c++)
    contacts[c] = contacts[c+1];
```

Then you can reallocate for the smaller dynamic array. Structs can be assigned to compatible structs, so you don't need to assign the fields of the structs individually.